Hydrostatic Shell Test - ASME B16.34
I have a vessel that was supposed to be tested at (minimum) 1.5 x MAWP, as per ASME B16.34 section 7.1. Vessel enclosure is made of cast WCB and it is of class 150.
However, due to operator error the vessel was tested at 2xMAWP. How can we verify (or assume) that 2xMAWP is okay... B16.34 does not set an upper limit for the shell test, only a minimum.
Much appreciated. Thanks.

So tested and survived or tested and failed?

the vessel was tested for 2 minutes only and it was ok. It is not whether or not it survived this short test, but what is the upper limit for the pressure test.. can we go up to 3xMAWP? what defines that?

The material, thickness, quality defines the max limit. Once you define those you can calculate the theoretical max. If you really want to know then do destructive testing to confirm your theoretical calculation.

It is weird there is no upper limit on test pressure. In EN standards, you need to check the structure also for pressure testing, for which you take higher allowable stress than for normal operation.
